# Win Server 2008 Foundation - SqlServer 2008 stops to accept connections?

Tags: sql-server-2008, limit, foundation, windows-server

I have a server machine with Windows 2008 Server R2 Foundation installed, that I use for hosting SqlServer 2008 service. There is no additional user registered on the OS, the clients asks only for connection with sqlserver. I've notice that periodically some clients stop working when trying to connect to sqlserver, while in the same time other clients are working properly. I know there are some limits on concurrent connections for foundation edition, but I can't understand which limit I'm breaking. Some ideas?

Comment: You might find some help for this at http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 Foundation limits include:

- 15 User Limit
- 50 TS Connections
- 50 RRAS Connections
- 10 TAS Connections
- 30 SMB Connections
- 1 socket systems only
- 8GB maximum memory support
- No virtualization use right

from: https://msmvps.com/blogs/bradley/archive/2009/08/05/windows-server-2008-foundation.aspx

You can run [sp_who](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx) and see all the connections that are being used but based on my understanding 30 is the limit.